# Apcahe parquet wasm in plain html and javascript

Tags: parquet, webassembly

We have a significant amount of data that needs to be loaded in the browser. Passing this data in Parquet format to the browser can significantly reduce network latency and file reads. We've come across "parquet-wasm", but it appears their solutions are only available for Node.js. How can we implement this functionality in the browser so that the data conversion occurs client-side? Additionally, if anyone has any insights on implementing "duckdb-wasm", we would appreciate hearing about it.